# How did {0}, {1}, etc become the standard for formatting strings?

Tags: .net, string, history

Just curious about this in the history of development... how did brackets with the array index (`{0}`, `{1}`, and so on) become the standard of string formatting?

Any special significance, or something somebody picked out of midair in the 80's?

Comment: @Paul, .NET's string.Format(), and Regex replacement expressions are two places that stick out in my mind

Answer (score 5):

Actually, back in the 80's, the formatting string standard was `printf`, with format strings such as `%d` for integers or `%s` for strings, and obscure format modifiers (such as `%06d` which draws an integer and pads it to the left with zeros until it reaches six characters). The reasoning was that the C type system was very poor, and it was impossible for `printf`to guess what the data it received was (was it a pointer to a string? an integer? a floating-point number) which made it necessary to specify the type of the arguments inside the format string. This approach remained.

This format was carried over from C (and C++) to many languages (Java, PHP, OCaml, Scilab...) and several tools (Firebug's `console.log` function, for instance).

The earliest I've seen the `{0}` format was in C#, in the early 2000s. I haven't seen it a lot outside C# so far.

Comment: It's much older than that, I remember seeing it at least as early as the mid-90's (I can't remember more than that though).

Comment: The [Python `.format()` function](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) also uses the `{0}` format, adopted from .NET.

Comment: F# brings `printf` and friends to the .NET framework. It's strongly-typed, so you get a compiler error if you try to pass a string value to a format string containing a `%d`.

Comment: @Joel Mueller : so does OCaml. Type safety on formatting strings is the best thing since sliced strongly-types bread.

Comment: I'm sure F# got the idea from OCaml, in fact. But I agree, I much prefer using F#'s string formatting functions to the .NET ones, even though I have easy access to both kinds.

Answer (score 2):

[Taligent MessageFormat](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/intl/datamgmt/messageFormat.html#format). 1990s. Also in JDK 1.1 (which came from Taligent) and ICU (==)

Comment: Some C# programmer used a time machine to seed the idea at Taligent.  This is why you're not getting up-voted.

Comment: That would explain a lot, actually. Too bad they didn't send a crate of modern SODIMMs and SATA drives with the idea. T was ahead of the platform capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it is the actual origin, but the ICU (International Components for Unicode) project uses curly braces in [message formatting](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/messages) and was first released as open source in 1999. To my knowledge it is not a standard, but it is nice to have some form agreement on the handling of Unicode text formatting between different programming languages (at least implementations/bindings exist for C++, Java and PHP (not sure about C#)). You can read more about the entire project at userguide.icu-project.org.

Comment: it supports named arguments and plurals, now. it came from Taligent though, see my other answer.

Comment: I noticed your answer, but unfortunately I can't upvote yet ;). Nice to see such a quick response from an authority on the subject too, btw.